# OpenGL LINK Error in OpenCV project

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, visual-studio-2012, opengl-es

I'm making a project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 with C++ language and it needs both OpenCV and OpenGL. I have done half of my project but only with OpenCV, and now I have to add the OpenGL in my project.

I'm using the OpenGL tutorial setup from here: http://aschultz.us/blog/archives/176/comment-page-1#comment-61698, but it gave me this error:

```
error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glut32.lib'
```

Then I tried to make a new trial project with only OpenGL in it and it works just fine! Please help me solve this error, I've tried googling and I haven't found any answers.

**UPDATE**

I just found out that the source for my problem is that I changed the platform in my OpenCV project from Win32 to x64 (Build > Configuration Manager) because I'm using the x64 version of OpenCV since my laptop is 64 bit. I also have tried to change the platform in my trial OpenGL program and it gave me the same error. Any ideas of how to solve this?

**UPDATE 01/05**

so I just added the directories to:

C/C++ > Additional Include Directories
with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include"

and in

Linker > Additonal Library Directories
with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib"

the same way that OpenCV configured. I compiled it but it gave me new error:

```
error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'   E:\- School -\ITS\TA\Coba\FingAR\FingAR\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll)
```

Anyone have an idea how to solve this? I found other people who have same problems with me but they still haven't solved it either...

**UPDATE 01/05, 19:50 GMT+7**
So my friend told me to change the OpenCV project platform back to Win32, and now it works. Thanks for everyone who helped me in the comment box! :D

Comment: can you the linker command lines of both projects?

Comment: @Micka sorry I don't really get what did you mean...

Comment: in visual studio at "project properties" at "linker settings" the last point should be sth. like "command line". please copy an paste it for both of your projects

Comment: @Micka but actually there is only one project... or did you mean the command line between the trial project and the actual OpenCV project should be the same?

Comment: I agree with micka, it looks like you haven't included it in the linker settings.

Comment: @rzld I meant you to add the command line of your OpenCV project and the command line of your trial project so that we can see what you are trying to do. They should not be the same, but probably they differ in the parts that are relevant for adding OpenGL to your old OpenCV project. Probably you just have to add the path in "additional library directories" or sth like that, but posting the command line would tell us more :)

Comment: @Micka I think I just found the problem: it's because in my OpenCV project I changed the Platform from Win32 to x64. I tried to change the platform in my trial project (with OpenGL only) and the same error appears when I compiled the project... but I haven't found how to solve it :(

Comment: Do you use glut32.lib of 64 bit for x64 configuration? Because it is not the same file as for 32 bit configuration.

Comment: @unick well since it's the problem, I think I've been using the 32 bit version... I'll try to find the ones for 64 bit later

Comment: @Unick how can I find the libs for x64?

Comment: @Micka so I just added the directories to C/C++ > Additional Include Directories > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include" and in Linker > Additonal Library Directories > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib" the same way that OpenCV configured. I compiled it but it gave me new error: Error 1 error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64' E:\- School -\ITS\TA\Coba\FingAR\FingAR\msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP110D.dll)

Comment: can you create a new 64 bit trial opengl project?

Comment: You can find it in this archve. http://files.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/development/GLUT/freeglut-MSVC.zip More information: http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/

Comment: @Unick I can't open those websites, it said the webpage not available :/ anyway I just resolved my own problem by changing the OpenCV project platform back to Win32, and now the program can run properly with openGL in it... thanks for your, Micka and GPPK's help, by the way!